# Working with data-icon in CSS

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

```
/* Use the following CSS code if you want to use data attributes for inserting your icons */
[data-icon]:before {
  font-family: 'Flat-UI-Icons';
  content: attr(data-icon);
  speak: none;
```

I saw this code in one of the bootstrap theme template. How does data-icon or attr(data-icon) works? i cant seem to display the "image/words" of the example i had, it's empty now. I tried

**`<a href="#fakelink" class="fui-flat">text here</a>`**

The text here's font doesnt seem to be the same as the example's one and also , the example didnt have anything between the a tags.

Please advice. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The css above will affect what happens before each instance of data-icon and not the link shown

They are a css3 feature.  Attribute selectors alow you to to apply formatting to elements based on certain attributes.

[att^=val] – the “begins with” selector
[att$=val] – the “ends with” selector
[att*=val] – the “contains” selector

good description [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/attribute-selectors/) which is where above taken from and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)